Cant find the way to add in CKeditor5 page breaker plugin in Angular
I followed CKeditor5 documentation (how to integrate CKeditor5 in angular app) by this url

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/integrations/angular.html

But I didn`t find example of adding page breaker plugin to this app
I found this example

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/page-break.html

but it isn`t suitable for integrating this plugin in angular

For ckeditor5 this is the only way to add plugin in the ckeditor bar. Or else see this https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-page-break
